# set minDate of next datepicker instance based on previous datepicker date + 1 day

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

#### HTML

```
<label for="checkIn">Check in</label>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="checkIn" id="checkIn"   />
<label  for="checkOut">Check out</label>
<input type="text"  readonly="readonly" name="checkOut" id="checkOut"   />
```

#### javaScript

```
var dates = $( "#checkIn, #checkOut" ).datepicker({
               autoSize: true,
               minDate: "+0",
               maxDate: "+6M",
               onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                     var option = this.id == "checkIn" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                     instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                     date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                                 instance.settings.dateFormat 
                              || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                                  selectedDate, instance.settings );
                    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
                }
   });
```

now what I want that,  whenever a user set any date for `checkIn`, `checkOut` should be next to that selected date along with all other options.

see the [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/JdYap/) for the same

I tried a lot but not succeed. Please help me what logic to apply?

Answer (score 2):

Try to separate the fields and initiate datepicker separately, and then, try this:

```
    $('#date1').datepicker({
        constrainInput: true, 
        dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy',
        // Once change, set date2 min date
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('#date2').datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
        }
    });

    $('#date2').datepicker({
        constrainInput: true, 
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'D, dd M yy'
    });
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: What is `datetext` and what means by `contraintInput`

Comment: dataText is the current selected date, constraitInput can be ignored, i just dun want to allow user to key in non-date thing in my textbox :)

Answer (score 2):

shennyL answer didn't account for selected date + n.

So:

On your #checkIn place:

```
minDate: 0, //sets the minDate offset to 0, meaning today.
onSelect: function() {
             var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
             if (date) {
                  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                  $("#checkOut").datepicker("option", "minDate", date)
             }
          }
```

This works quite ok as far as I can tell. You may just need to clean up some code on your fiddle perhaps ?